# Looping through rows in the table using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an **html table** formatted in the following way:

```
ID | Name  | Address

1  | Name1 | Address1

2  | Name2 | Address2
```

I want to loop thru the table and need to create XML data in this format:

```
<xml>
<row1>
<id>1</id>
<Name>Name1</Name1>
<Address>Address1</Address>
</row1>
```

How can I do this using PHP? can anyone suggest an example?

Comment: [This article](http://www.kirupa.com/web/mysql_xml_php.htm) explains the code.

Comment: am having as html table,not mysql table, i want to loop thru each row in the html table and need to create as xml data for each row

Comment: **where did you get** this html table?

Comment: I think he is actually talking about a plain ol' HTML table not a MySQL one. @user515675 - show some effort please. Also, are you planing to use a PEAR lib to generate XML or the DomDocument class...or?

Comment: OMG, so, it's not an HTML table but HTML **form**?

Comment: yes. its a html form with the above table format, user inputs the values and when user click submit i want to convert each row as xml data

Comment: @user515675 - all due respect but, what have you tried? We are all busy people here and we don't really have time to develop other people's code. If you need a research starting point, let us know, but please don't expect us to fully develop this. It is not the about the work, it is about the principle. just my two cents

Comment: no am not expecting the full code, just say some ideas and concept to do this, so i can develop my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> just say some ideas and concept to do this

```
<?
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  foreach ($_POST['id'] as $i => $id) {
    $name = $_POST['name'][$i];
    $address = $_POST['address'][$i];
  }
}
?>
<form method=post>
  <input type=text name="id[1]"><input type=text name="name[1]"><input type=text name="address[1]">
  <input type=text name="id[2]"><input type=text name="name[2]"><input type=text name="address[2]">
</form>
```